# How can I display a random image each time a particular web pages loads?

Tags: html, image, random, display

I have a particular page that is part of a website; it is coded directly in HTML. I have four images, and want to display a random one of them in a particular place on that page each time the page is loaded by anyone.

I have tried numerous examples; the one that seemed most logical to me was to have a function that would return a random integer from 1-4, and then I could simply put

so if the function happened to return a "2", the HTML that would execute would be  giving me

I have found functions that are supposed to provide a random 0, 1, 2, or 3, but I can't get this approach to work. I am not a programming expert, although I am pretty good in straightforward HTML.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to learn a few lines of Javascript, and write yourself an [onload()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) function, that uses [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of images which you would like to use, and then pick a random image from this array and display it to your HTML once the DOM has loaded.

See example below:

```js
const images = ["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512453979798-5ea266f8880c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80", 
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519834785169-98be25ec3f84?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  const randImageIndex = ~~(Math.random() * images.length);
  document.getElementById('randImg').src = images[randImageIndex];
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>My random image website</h1>
<h3>Take a look around</h3>

<img id="randImg" src="" alt="Random image" />

<p>This is some text</p>
```

The above only works if you have one image in your HTML which you wish to randomize, if you want multiple images randomized you can use the following, just give the image you wish to randomize the class `randImg`:

```js
const images = ["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512453979798-5ea266f8880c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80", 
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519834785169-98be25ec3f84?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('randImg')].forEach(e => {
    const randImageIndex = ~~(Math.random() * images.length);
    e.src = images[randImageIndex];
  }); 
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>My random image website</h1>
<h3>Take a look around</h3>

<img class="randImg" src="" alt="Random image" />

<p>This is some text1</p>
<img class="randImg" src="" alt="Random image" />
<p>This is more text2</p>
<img class="randImg" src="" alt="Random image" />
```